# How to swap a subset of attributes between two elements

Tags: javascript

I am attempting to swap some attributes of one element with another - this will be done immediately before moving the elements around in the document, maybe between one parent and another.
I have the code below, but it fails because there is no temporary element to enable the swap.

```js
let elem1 = document.getElementById("item1");
   let elem2 = document.getElementById("item2");
   let before = document.getElementById("before");
   let after = document.getElementById("after");
     
   before.innerHTML = 'before: ' + showData(elem1,elem2);
   swapAttributes(elem1,elem2);
   after.innerHTML = 'after: ' + showData(elem1,elem2);
   
    function showData(a,b) {
      let data1 = a.dataset;
      let data2 = b.dataset;
      return data1.keepRow + "," + data1.keepCol + " and " + data2.keepRow + "," + data2.keepCol;
  
    }
    function swapAttributes(el1,el2) {

        // retain data that needs keeping 
        const el1Keeps = [], el2Keeps = [];
        [...el1.attributes].forEach( attr => {
             if (attr.nodeName.startsWith( "data-keep-")) {
                 el1Keeps.push(attr);
             }
        });
        [...el2.attributes].forEach( attr => {
            if (attr.nodeName.startsWith( "data-keep-")) {
                el2Keeps.push(attr);
            }
        });
        // swap it back into other elements
        el2Keeps.forEach(keepAttr => {
            el1.setAttribute(keepAttr.name,keepAttr.value)
        })
        el1Keeps.forEach(keepAttr => {
            el2.setAttribute(keepAttr.name,keepAttr.value)
        })
        
   }
```

```html
<div id="item1" data-keep-row=1 data-keep-col=1>item1</div>
<div id="item2" data-keep-row=2 data-keep-col=2>item2</div>
<p id="before"></p>
<p id="after"></p>
```

I have tried using a temporary element, which gives the correct change of attributes but it also requires the element's parents to swap children around which causes additional complications later.

I have read that 'destructuring assignment' can be used for this type of thing:

```
[a, b] = [b, a];
```

but I cannot see how to apply that to my situation.

Comment: You can't do it because you're calling `setAttribute()`, not doing assignments.

Comment: Please post a [mcve] here, not at jsfiddle. You can use a [Stack Snippet](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/358992/ive-been-told-to-create-a-runnable-example-with-stack-snippets-how-do-i-do) to make it executable.

Comment: Thanks for showing me how to do runnable snippets! Done now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that you're saving the `attr` objects. These are references to the original object's attributes, so they get modified when you later call `setAttribute()` on that object.

Instead, create new objects in the `el1Keeps` and `el2Keeps`.

```js
function swapAttributes(el1, el2) {
  // retain data that needs keeping 
  const el1Keeps = [],
    el2Keeps = [];
  [...el1.attributes].forEach(attr => {
    if (attr.nodeName.startsWith("data-keep-")) {
      el1Keeps.push({
        name: attr.name,
        value: attr.value
      });
    }
  });
  [...el2.attributes].forEach(attr => {
    if (attr.nodeName.startsWith("data-keep-")) {
      el2Keeps.push({
        name: attr.name,
        value: attr.value
      });
    }
  });
  // swap it back into other elements
  el2Keeps.forEach(keepAttr => {
    el1.setAttribute(keepAttr.name, keepAttr.value)
  })
  el1Keeps.forEach(keepAttr => {
    el2.setAttribute(keepAttr.name, keepAttr.value)
  })
}

let elem1 = document.getElementById("item1");
let elem2 = document.getElementById("item2");
let before = document.getElementById("before");
let after = document.getElementById("after");

before.innerHTML = 'before: ' + showData(elem1, elem2);
swapAttributes(elem1, elem2);
after.innerHTML = 'after: ' + showData(elem1, elem2);

function showData(a, b) {
  let data1 = a.dataset;
  let data2 = b.dataset;
  return data1.keepRow + "," + data1.keepCol + " and " + data2.keepRow + "," + data2.keepCol;

}
```

```html
<div id="item1" data-keep-row=1 data-keep-col=1>item1</div>
<div id="item2" data-keep-row=2 data-keep-col=2>item2</div>
<p id="before"></p>
<p id="after"></p>
```

Since you're only swapping the `data-` attributes, it seems like you should be able to do

```
[el1.dataset, el2.dataset] = [el2.dataset, el1.dataset];
```

Unfortunately this doesn't work because `dataset` is a read-only property. You can only assign to `element.dataset.XXX`, not `element.dataset` as a whole.

Comment: Thank you. The silly thing is, I had that method earlier. But I'm in the process of converting all to TypeScript (which I am very  new to) and the transpiler didn't like it. So I changed it, but wrongly! . I now have `el2_keeps.push({  name: attr.name,  value: attr.value  } as Attr);` and all is happy and working.